# Chapter and section number in margin and align chapter prefix with text in scrbook

Tags: sectioning, chapters, scrbook

I try to customize my chapter headings, without using additional packages like **titlesec**, as I'd like to avoid incompatibilities with all the other stuff around.

I almost have what I want:

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=12pt,                                            
  BCOR=15mm,                                              
  DIV=15, 
  twoside=true,
  open=right,
  chapterprefix = true,
  headings=twolinechapter,
  headings=big,                                     
]{scrbook} 


\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers = OldStyle,Ligatures = TeX,SmallCapsFeatures = {Renderer=Basic}]{Minion Pro}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\Huge}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{5\baselineskip}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{2\baselineskip}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
                {\fontsize{20}{30}\scshape\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}
                \fontsize{120}{30}\selectfont\thechapter\autodot\enskip}
\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\raggedleft}

\setkomafont{section}{\Large\rmfamily}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello World!}
\section{Section 1}
\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

There is just on detail missing:

### How can I place chapter and section numbers in the margin and align title and prefix with the text?

So basically I try to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Your first call to `\fontsize` is not useful without a call to `\selectfont`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit but I get visual changes, when I change the fontsize?

Comment: Here, you get visual change because the following `\scshape` implicitly calls  `\selectfont` for you. If you comment `\scshape`, your call to `\fontsize` has no effect. It is better to explicitly call `\selectfont` just after `\fontsize{...}{...}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the following definition for sections and alike

```
\renewcommand*\othersectionlevelsformat[3]{%
  \llap{#3\autodot\enskip}%
}
```

and change the definition of `\chapterformat` to

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  {\fontsize{20}{30}\scshape\chapappifchapterprefix{}}%
  \fontsize{120}{30}\selectfont\rlap{\thechapter\autodot}%
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=12pt,
  BCOR=15mm,
  DIV=15,
  twoside=true,
  open=right,
  chapterprefix = true,
  headings=twolinechapter,
  headings=big,
]{scrbook}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers = OldStyle,Ligatures = TeX,SmallCapsFeatures = {Renderer=Basic}]{Minion Pro}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\Huge}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{5\baselineskip}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{2\baselineskip}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  {\fontsize{20}{30}\scshape\chapappifchapterprefix{}}%
  \fontsize{120}{30}\selectfont\rlap{\thechapter\autodot}%
}
\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\raggedleft}

\renewcommand*\othersectionlevelsformat[3]{%
  \llap{#3\autodot\enskip}%
}

\setkomafont{section}{\Large\rmfamily}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello World!}
\section{Section 1}
\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### UPDATE (KOMA-Script v3.17)

Starting with KOMA-Script v3.17, `\othersectionlevelsformat` doesn't work as before, so, instead of using

```
\renewcommand*\othersectionlevelsformat[3]{%
  \llap{#3\autodot\enskip}%
}
```

you will have to use

```
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \llap{\thesection\autodot\enskip}%
}
```

instead. If you also want that behavior for subsections, use

```
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
  \llap{\thesubsection\autodot\enskip}%
}
```

and so on.

Comment: (+1) Nice answer.  There is a problem though. The entries in `\tableofcontents` will have a huge white space in-between, how can we solve this, @karlkoeller ?